# want to use the variable in this file not in the import one

Tags: python, import, global-variables

Hey guys here is the problem that I have faced in my project. Here I use a simple example to explain it. When I try to run the main.py, I want to use the variable in this module not in the helper, but the output result is always 2 even when i delete the global variable "a". **Is there any way without inputting the function argument?** Hope someone can help :( 
 
**helper.py**

```
a = 2
def test():
   print(a)
```

**main.py**

```
from helper import *

del globals()["a"]
if __init__ == "__main__":
    a = 10
    test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just modify the attribute:

**main.py**

```
import helper

if __name__ == "__main__":
    helper.a = 10
    helper.test()
```

Output:

```
10
```

**Edit:**

You could try:

**helper.py**

```
a = [2]
def test():
   print(a[0])
```

**main.py**

```
from helper import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a.clear()
    a.append(10)
    test()
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: Is there a way without passing argument

Comment: @YanJimmy Edited my answer check it out, remember what to do if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Another question. Because in my project there are a lot of functions and variables that I want to use, that's why I write from helper import *. My question is if I only want to modify some of the global variable, can I still use from helper import * ?

Comment: @YanJimmy You can do both, you can do `import helper` and also `from helper import *` as well, remember to accept and upvote if it helps :P

Comment: If I do from helper import * , how can i change the global variable a? tensorflow_test.a?

Comment: @YanJimmy Check my **Edit:**

Comment: But what if i don't want to use a list. I want to assign an int to the variable. Is it possible?

Comment: @YanJimmy Than it isn't possible, because integers are immutable

Comment: @YanJimmy My solutions are the only possible ways